# Converting differential equation into sturm -Liouville

Tags: sturm-liouville

Convert the following equation to the form of a Sturm-Louville equation.
$$3x^2y''(x)+4xy'+6y(x)+\lambda y(x)=0,x>0$$

I used [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2866674/469000)

But the substitution was tedious and I couldn't find the sturm-Liouville form. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be written as
$$
  a(x)y''(x)+b(x)y'(x)+c(x)y(x)+\lambda d(x)y(x)=0,
$$
where
$$
    a(x)=3x^2,\; b(x)=4x,\; c(x)=6,\;\; d(x)=1.
$$
Using the problem I referenced, start with the substitution
$$
    y=\rho(x)f(x),
$$
where
$$ \rho(x)=\sqrt{3x^2}\exp\left(-\int\frac{4x}{6x^2}dx\right) \\
   =\sqrt{3}x\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\ln(x)\right) \\
     =\sqrt{3}xx^{-2/3}=\sqrt{3}x^{1/3}
$$
This transforms your problem in $y$ to a new problem in $f$:
$$
   -\frac{d}{dx}\left(3x^2\frac{df}{dx}\right)+\left(\frac{(b-a')^2}{4a}+\frac{(b-a')'}{2}-c\right)f=\lambda f(x).
$$
Using $b-a'=4x-6x=-2x$ gives the following Sturm-Liouville equation in normal form:
$$
   -\frac{d}{dx}\left(3x^2\frac{df}{dx}\right)
   +\left(\frac{1}{3}-1-6\right)f=\lambda f \\
   -\frac{d}{dx}\left(3x^2\frac{df}{dx}\right)-\frac{20}{3}f=\lambda f$$